# Docker container extremely slow when network mode host

Tags: docker, networking, wildfly

I’ve had a working setup with a docker-compose and especially a wildfly image running in network mode = host.
Since the company stopped the internet connection, the startup of the container is extremely slow and end with a timeout.

I found out that when I run the container in network mode = bridge, it is working just normally.

I tried with a docker-hub wildfly empty image to be sure the issue is not on my side and it’s the same problem.
It starts in 5s in bridge, and 33 in host…

I use the command :

> docker run --network host jboss/wildfly:18.0.1.Final

to start the container in network host mode.

My docker version is 19.03.15 and it’s running in a VM in bridge mode.

I need the network mode host because we access the containers from outside the VM and they need to communicate with each other.

I can’t use internet anymore on the VM neither the host machine because of the security policy of the company.

So I’m looking for a solution to still use network host without this not-understandable slowness…
I’m not sure if it’s coming from wildfly or the docker itself ?

Thanks by advance,
Loïc.

Comment: You don't need to disable Docker networking just to get access to a container; the `docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` option is the standard way to publish a container's ports to elsewhere (in your setup it would make ports visible on the VM's IP address).

Comment: Thanks David for your answer.
I tried your solution but I have problems with Postgres and Zookeeper running in the same docker-compose. Wildfly seems to not be able to communicate with those 2 (connection refused)… do you have a solution ? 
Thanks